# Directly upgrading from SP 2013 to SERVICE PACK-1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, service-pack

I am having a SP 2013 in my dev. environment having one WFE and another dedicated server for SQL.
Since my customer has installed SP2013 On-Premises SP1 AND sql server 2012 sp2 on their environment,I need to keep my dev. env in sync with customer's infra.

So, what should I start doing with my dev. env? Can I directly upgrade the dev en from SP 2013 to SP 2013 SP1, by running the ISO-disc image file of SP 2013 SP1 ?
If I run like this, will i lose all the contents from the current install?

or should i remove my sharepoint 2013 RTM instance from my dev machine and install from the SP 2013 with service pack-1 disc image? 
My team members are working on different modules using this sp 2013 rtm version, so i dont want to break or stop/lose the their work.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to rebuild / re install the SharePoint. You have to follow these steps.

- Backup your farm( either SharePoint full backup or SQL server database BackUp), this is for safety purpose.
- Install the SP1[( download it from here)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42544)
- Run the SharePoint Product Config Wizard
- Now test your farm

You farm is now at SP1 level.

Comment: i already have the disc image file of SP1 in my D drive. Also what should i do about SQL server ? Customer is having  SQL SERVER 2012 SP2 .and i am having SQL SERVER 2012 only without service pack. So, would need advice: 1) first i will stop the current development work on this server. 2) i will run the SQL SERVER SP 2 and upgrade the sql server to SP2 . 3) Now i will run the SP 2013 SP1  disc image file and install as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I would upgrade sql to sp2 and tested, after that I will apply sp1 to sharepoint and test it.